# How to structure an algorithm in Python that populates a list with filtered values that are sourced from random generation?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, random, filter

I want to create a list of 25 items all with a specific key in a key/value pair, but the pairs that I'm receiving from the API function call are somewhat random in nature. I'm not sure what the most efficient way to populate the list is.

Take this arbitrary example:

A function generates a specified number of random animals with names as a key/value pair, so

`getAnimals(3)`

generates

```
{'Cat':'Ted'}
{'Horse': 'Fred'}
{'Bird': 'Jed}
```

So if I want a dictionary of 25 animals that are all cats the desired result would look like:

```
[
    {'Cat': 'Ted'}, 
    {'Cat': 'Aaron'}, 
    {'Cat': 'Fluffy'},
    ...
]
```

I know generating one item at a time is definitely not ideal. Right now I'm theorizing that I should generate 25 items at once, filter out the non-cat entries, and then call the function again for the remaining number of spots to fill. Repeat until dict is full. Is this the most efficient way to go about this? If not, what would be the best way to structure this algorithm?

Comment: It sounds like you really need, say, two different functions: One generates all random animals, but the other allows you to pass in the particular animal that you require.

Comment: Your expected output is missing keys in the outer dictionary.  Do you expect a list as the output rather than a dictionary ?

Comment: Does your `getAnimals` function have a way to pre-determine the number of animals of a given type to output.  There may not be 25 cats if you call getAnimals(100), let alone getAnimals(25).  Would it be acceptable to call getAnimals() repeatadly ?

Comment: It **really** depends on the details of how you are generating the items.

Comment: @AlainT. no, the `getAnimals` function is just a simple conceptual example for a private API call that gives back the number of "animals" specified as a pseudo-random list (not a dict, edited the mistake). It unfortunately takes no other params so it would have to be called repeatedly. I'm looking for the most efficient way to make those calls.

Comment: "So if I want a dictionary of 25 animals..." I think you mean a list here, too, right?

Comment: "I'm not sure what the most efficient way to populate the list is." Don't worry overly much about run-time efficiency at this point. Write something that works and is easy to understand and change first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulating your `getAnimals` function as a generator that yields random choices of species and names in a one-key dictionary:

```
import random

species = ['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Frog']
names  = ['Ted','Aaron','Jed','Fluffy','Tom','Max']
def getAnimals(count):
    for _ in range(count):
        yield {random.choice(species):random.choice(names)}
```

Example run:

```
print(*getAnimals(5),sep='\n')
{'Cat': 'Ted'}
{'Frog': 'Jed'}
{'Bird': 'Max'}
{'Frog': 'Fluffy'}
{'Dog': 'Max'}
```

You can fill your 25 cat list using a while loop that asks for the missing number of items in the result list:

```
result = []
while len(result)<25:
    for animal in getAnimals(25-len(result)):
        if 'Cat' in animal:
            result.append(animal)

print(result)

[{'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Jed'}, {'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Tom'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Tom'}, {'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Max'}, {'Cat': 'Max'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Fluffy'}, {'Cat': 'Jed'}, {'Cat': 'Tom'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Aaron'}, {'Cat': 'Max'}, {'Cat': 'Aaron'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Tom'}, {'Cat': 'Tom'}, {'Cat': 'Max'}, {'Cat': 'Jed'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Aaron'}, {'Cat': 'Ted'}, {'Cat': 'Tom'}, {'Cat': 'Tom'}, 
 {'Cat': 'Aaron'}]
```

If there is a benefit to generating larger batches but you don't want to systematically request too many (e.g. if you're getting this from a web service or database), you can start with an estimated count and refine the estimate at each iteration based on the ratio of Cats found so far:

```
target    = 25
result    = []
generated = 0
estimate  = target
while len(result)<target:
    for animal in getAnimals(round(estimate) or target):
        generated += 1
        if 'Cat' in animal:
            result.append(animal)
            if len(result) == target:
                break
    estimate = (target-len(result))*generated/max(1,len(result))
```